# Put long value into Bundle

Tags: android, android-bundle

A [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) can save many types of data: `short`, `byte`, another `Bundle`, `ArrayList<Integer>`, yet not a simple `long`.

How can this best be achieved? Must it be converted to a `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: see `Bundle#getLong` and `Bundle#putLong`

Comment: I'm fairly sure there IS a putLong method. Are you sure there isn't?

Comment: @JamesWierzba: there is none in `Bundle`, there is one in `BaseBundle`, as Ilya answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure? There are [putLong()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html#putLong(java.lang.String,%20long)) in docs.

Comment: Note that it's declared on `BaseBundle`, and so will show up in the inherited methods when looking at `Bundle`.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a long inside a bundle^^

Here is how to store your value

```
//store the long value
long myNumber = 123456789;
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putLong("MY_KEY", myNumber);

//then start your activity
```

Here is how to retrieve

```
//retrieve the long value
long value = bundle.getLong("MY_KEY");
```